# <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated"> not firing with ContentTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, contenttemplateselector

I'm trying to animate the Background Color of a Border in a DataTemplate for a DataObject when a Child Property of the DataObject changes.
The DataObject is a Class called Test with two Properties, Number and Text.
I have an ObservableCollection of DataObjects called Numbers.
In a Task I update the Number Property at a regular Interval.

```
<Window
  x:Class="WpfAnimationTest.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAnimationTest"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  Title="MainWindow"
  Width="800"
  Height="450"
  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="NumberTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
            </DataTemplate>

            <local:ValueTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector">
                <local:ValueTemplateSelector.NumberTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NumberTemplate}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:ValueTemplateSelector.NumberTemplate>
            </local:ValueTemplateSelector>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Test}">
                <Border x:Name="UpdateBorder" Background="Aqua">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock
                          Width="50"
                          Margin="10"
                          Text="{Binding Text}" />
                        <ContentControl
                          Width="50"
                          Margin="10"
                          Content="{Binding Number}"
                          ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" />

                        <!--
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NumberTemplate}"
                        -->
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                      FillBehavior="Stop"
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="UpdateBorder"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                      To="#C5AFFFAA"
                                      Duration="00:00:0.5" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfAnimationTest
{
    public class Locator
    {
        public Locator()
        {
            Main = new Main();
        }

        public Main Main { get; set; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Test> Numbers { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Test>();

        public Main()
        {
            var rnd = new Random(42);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Numbers.Add(new Test(){Number = i, Text = $"#: {i}"});
            }

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            Numbers[rnd.Next(9)] = new Test
                            {
                                Number = rnd.Next(30),
                                Text = $"# {rnd.Next(30) + 30}"
                            };
                        });
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    
    public class ValueTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <param name="container"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            return !(item is Test value)
                ? null
                : NumberTemplate;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public DataTemplate NumberTemplate { get; set; }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When using a ContentTemplate for the Number Property in the ContentControl the animation is working.
But when I use a ContentTemplateSelector the Animation is not triggered anymore.

What am I missing here?

Comment: There is a lot of redundant code. See my answer for a simplified version. Like all the ContentControls are redundant. So is the DataTemplateSelector and the related DataTemplates. If you want or have to use a DataTemplateSelector, define it directly on the `ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector`. This will help to improve your code significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data bindings are wrong, resulting in unhandled or unexpected data types.

Currently, your `ContentControl.Content` property (inside the `DataTemplate` for the type `Test`) binds to the `Test.Number` property of type `int`. Therefore, the object that is passed to the `DataTemplateSelector` is of type `int` and not `Test`. The condition in the `DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate` method will return false (as `int is not Test` is `true`) and make the `DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate` return `null` - no template. The XAML engine will call `ToString` on the `int` instance and is therefore able to display the value correctly (despite the lack of a `DataTemplate`).

### Solution

You must fix the binding on the `ContentControl.Content` property to bind to the `Test` instance instead of binding to the `Test.Number` property:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Test}">
    <Border x:Name="UpdateBorder"
            Background="Aqua">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Width="50"
                    Margin="10"
                    Text="{Binding Text}" />
        <ContentControl Width="50"
                        Margin="10"
                        Content="{Binding}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Now that that the `DataTemplateSelector` can work properly, you must also adjust the `NumberTemplate`, so that it can display the `Test.Number` property properly. Since we have modified the binding source for the `ContentControl.Content` property, the new data type is now `Test` (instead of `int`):

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="NumberTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type Test}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

### Remarks

There is a lot of redundant code here. You will achieve the same results by dropping all the templates and the `DataTemplateSelector` by defining the `ItemTemplate` for the `Test` items properly.
The following drastically simplified version should also work:

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Test}">
      <Border x:Name="UpdateBorder"
              Background="Aqua">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Width="50"
                      Margin="10"
                      Text="{Binding Text}" />
          <TextBlock Width="50"
                      Margin="10"
                      Text="{Binding Number, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
          <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
                <ColorAnimation FillBehavior="Stop"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="UpdateBorder"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="#C5AFFFAA"
                                Duration="00:00:0.5" />
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Grid.Resources>

  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution. You are right my Datatypes were not correct.
This was a simplified Problem from a far bigger project where I needed the ContentTemplateSelector.
The solution works for this simplified Problem. Still I cannot adopt it for some reason to my bigger Project. But I think I got a huge step forward with your hint for the wrong DataTypes.

Comment: As suggested, you should set the ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector to pick the proper template for the item.